# Why is SetActive not working in my script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A new problem has just appeared in my code. In OnTriggerEnter i'm testing if the player collides with the obstacle. When I tell the script to display a message it works fine. But when I replace the `Debug.Log("test")`,   with:  `deadScreen.gameObject.SetActive(true)`  to enable my death screen, it just dosen't work and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

⠀⠀

Here's my CollisionWithObstacle script that's attached to my obstacle:⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionWithObstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject deadScreen;
    private bool isShown = false;
    public static bool alive = true;
    void Start()
    {
        isShown = false;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        alive = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!alive)
        {
            deadScreen.SetActive(true);
            deadScreen.active = true;
            isShown = true;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you assigned `deadScreen` in editor? What is displayed in Console?

Comment: Can you check if it is actually active in Unity Editor im the Hierachy? Also what happens if you enable it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time that I encountered this problem is because other scripts are interacting with the gameobject. Furthermore if it's UI you can try to use [CanvasGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanvasGroup.html) and switch alpha between 0-1 and block raycasts. Let me know how it works out for you